# $K/F$ Galois Extension, $H \leq G$, where $G$ the Galois group, then there is $\alpha \in K$ s.t. $H=\{\sigma \in G : \sigma \alpha = \alpha\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $K/F$ be a finite Galois extension of fields with Galois group $G$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then there is $\alpha \in K$ such that $H=\{\sigma \in G : \sigma \alpha = \alpha\}$.

My proof is this:

Consider the fixed field $E$ of $H$. Let $\alpha \in E$ be such that if $\alpha \in E' \subseteq K$ then $E\subseteq E'$. Then $H = \{\sigma \in G : \sigma \alpha = \alpha \}$ since if $\sigma \in H$, then sigma fixes $\alpha$. Conversely, if $\sigma \in G$ fixes alpha, then by choice of $\alpha$, $\sigma$ is contained in some subgroup $H'$ with fixed field $E'$ containing $\alpha$ and $E' \supseteq E$. In particular, since $E \subseteq E' \iff H' \subseteq H$, we have $\sigma \in H$. The result follows.

Does this work? I feel like I might be missing something since I (apparently) did not use the finiteness assumption on the field extension.

> People have posted (better) solutions but I'm still interested in knowing whether what I came up with is correct.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but did you not use the finiteness assumption to apply Galois Correspondence?

Comment: How do you an $\alpha$ with this property exists?

Comment: @ Bernard. It's clear it exists. If $F$ is any subgroup of $K$ with $E$ not contained in $F$ and $F$ not contained in $E$ then $E-F$ is nonempty. Also, there has to be an $\alpha$ in $E$ not contained in any proper subfield of $E$ since $E$ is strictly larger than any proper subfield.

Comment: @ Andrew If it is the case that the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory is only true for finite extensions, then yes, I suppose I did.

Comment: $H$, being a subgroup of $G$, represents an intermediate field $F'$ with $F\subseteq F' \subseteq K$. Since these are all Galois extensions, then $F'$ is generated by a single element over $F$ (by the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem)). This is your $\alpha$.

Comment: @ Arthur  It's only the case that $F'/F$ is Galois if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Sorry, yes, of course. Still, the primitive element theorem holds, since we don't need Galois for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the assumption of finiteness of the extension when you assumed that exist $ \alpha $ as you choose. The existence of such $ \alpha $ is ensured by the Primitive element theorem and not necessary true for infinite extensions. From then on, your solution is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 3):

$E=K^H$, being a subextension of the Galois extension $K/F$ is a finite separable extension of $K$, hence by the *Primitive element theorem*, there exists $\alpha\in E$  such that $E=K(\alpha)$. Now, it isresults from the Galois correspondence that:
 $$H=\{\sigma\in G\mid \sigma(\alpha)=\alpha\}.$$